# Addition of matrices not working as intended with piecewise definition

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions

A somewhat minimal working example:

I define `p:={{1,0},{0,1}}`, `q:={{2,0},{0,2}}`, and finally

`a[t_]:=Piecewise[{{p,t>=0},{q,t<0}}].`

I have a problem adding matrices to `a[t]` when using assumptions.

In particular, `a[1]+p` looks like the intended `{{2,0},{0,2}}`, however

`Simplify[a[t]+p,t>=0]` results in `{{{{2,1},{1,2}},p},{p,{{2,1},{1,2}}}}` .

It appears that what `Simplify[a[t]+p,t>=0]` does is it generates the matrix whose i,j entry is created by adding the i,j th entry of a[t] to each entry in p.

How do I make `Simplify[a[t]+p,t>=0]` result in `{{2,0},{0,2}}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see what is going on by:

```
p := {{p11, p12}, {p21, p22}};
q := {{q11, q12}, {q21, q22}};
a[t_] := Piecewise[{{p, t >= 0}, {q, t < 0}}]
```

If we now say

```
a[1] + p
(*{{2 p11, 2 p12}, {2 p21, 2 p22}}*)
```

`a[1]`is first evaluated, resulting in the matrix `p` where we add another `p`. All clear as far.

Now if we specify:

```
a[t] + p
```

[image: (* *)]

`a[t]` is a function that is added to every element of p. It is treated like a scalar, MMA does not recognize that it is a vector valued function. If this is a bug or simply too big expectation, I do not know. And because `a[t] + p` is evaluate before `Simplify` we get what we get:

Simplify[a[t] + p, t >= 0]

[image]

However, we may simplify `a[t]` before adding p to get what we want:

Simplify[a[t], t > 0] + p

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! What a simple solution this is.

Comment: I would like to note that this causes some difficulties when trying to Simplify a function which is defined in terms of two other functions, each which have Piecewise definitions. Maybe not a bug, but too big of a request on the users part, as Daniel stated.