# How can I get a matrix valued function to act like a matrix instead of a scalar?

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions

A small example illustrating the issue:

If

```
p:={{1,0},{0,0}};
q:={{0,0},{0,1}};
a[t_]:=Piecewise[{{p,t<=0},{q,t>0}}];
```

And I then define

```
b[t_]:=a[t]+q;
```

I would hope that `Simplify[b[t],t<=0]` would return `p+q,` however running such code results in

```
{{q_{1,1}+p,q_{1,2}+p},{q_{2,1}+p,q_{2,2}+p}}
```

For more, see [my other question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240986/addition-of-matrices-not-working-as-intended-with-piecewise-definition), which has a great, concise solution by Daniel Huber. The core of the problem is when computing `a[t]+q`, `a[t]` is added to each entry of `q`, that is `a[t]` is treated like a scalar. The solution there is, instead of running `Simplify[b[t],t<=0]`, we run `Simplify[a[t],t<=0]+q`. This has an unfortunate side effect that if I wish to test `b` for a range of undetermined values of `t`, I have to dissect `b` and test its components at those values.

What I should do to get the desired effect of `Simplify[b[t],t<=0]` returns `p+q` and `Simplify[b[t],t>0]` returns `2q`, without breaking `b` apart manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `Piecewise` use `Boole`:

```
p := {{1, 0}, {0, 0}};
q := {{0, 0}, {0, 1}};
a[t_] := p Boole[t <= 0] + q Boole[t > 0];
b[t_] := a[t] + q;
Simplify[b[t], t <= 0]

(*{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}*)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll look in to the differences between Piecewise and Boole to figure out when I should use which.